# Comparison of two arrays in vbscript

Tags: arrays, vbscript

Is there a way to compare two arrays of identical size. It is important that dimension of the arrays can be more than 1.

For instance, it might be a function which takes value True only if elements of array arrA with indexes `(i, j, k, ...)` are equal to elements of array arrB with indexes `(i, j, k, ...)` for all indexes; and its value is `False` for other cases. I know there is temptation to use `"For Each...In arrA"` or at least nested `"For i=LBound(arrA,1) to UBound(arrA,1)...Next"` but this solution doesn't seem elegant and effective for multidimensional arrays.

Comment: It might not look elegant, but comparing multidimensional arrays will require to look in each dimension, which comes down to nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

From this link : [Compare two arrays and return matches](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=835519)

```
firstArr = Array("John", "Jacob", "Sam", "Bill")
secondArr = Array("Jen", "Bill", "Mike", "Steve", "John")
dim matchArr()
for i=0 to ubound(firstArr)
    for j=0 to ubound(secondArr)
        if strComp(firstArr(i), secondArr(j), 1)=0 then
           on error resume next
            redim preserve matchArr(ubound(matchArr)+1)
            if err.number<>0 then redim matchArr(0) : err.clear
            on error goto 0
            matchArr(ubound(matchArr))=firstArr(i)
        end if
    next
next
on error resume next
wscript.echo "The number of matches is " & ubound(matchArr)+1
if err.number<>0 then wscript.echo "No match is reported." : err.clear
on error goto 0
'etc etc other stuff
```

Comment: Hi Hackoo. Thank you for your answer but this is not exactly what I'm looking for. In your script the dynamic `matchArr` is populated with elements found in both one-dimensional arrays (`firstArr` and `secondArr`); and then `ubound(matchArr)-lbound(matchArr)+1` gives number of elements in the array. No doubts, this method is good to find the number of matching elements. But all I need is yes/no answer if `firstArr` is exact copy of `secondArr`. Worth noting that array `{{1,2},{3,4}}` is not the same as `{{1,2},{4,3}}` in this approach (though the same elements are used to build both matrixes).

Comment: Ah... one more thing. Nested loops is not what I would like to have in the solution. I still hope there is a much more effective way to detect the equality of the arrays.

Comment: Also, in general case dimension of `firstArr` and `secondArr` is unknown. In the script two arrays may change dimension with `ReDim` statement.